# Python OSError: Too many open files

Tags: python, windows-xp, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows XP.

My script relies on tempfile.mkstemp and tempfile.mkdtemp to create a lot of files and directories with the following pattern:

```
_,_tmp = mkstemp(prefix=section,dir=indir,text=True)

<do something with file>

os.close(_)
```

Running the script always incurs the following error (although the exact line number changes, etc.). The actual file that the script is attempting to open varies.

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'path\\to\\most\\recent\\attempt\\to\\open\\file'
```

Any thoughts on how I might debug this? Also, let me know if you would like additional information. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of use:

```
out = os.fdopen(_,'w')
out.write("Something")
out.close()

with open(_) as p:
    p.read()
```

Comment: Try opening fewer files at once; maybe open them just prior to reading/writing some data, or store information in a smaller number of files. `with` statements may also help.

Comment: I am only opening one at a time (occasionally two) before closing them. The "do something with file" is basically just writing to it...no processing. I am using the `with` statement every time I open files. To debug, I added a check to make sure that these were actually being closed.

Comment: It's possible the your use of a variable named `_` is the problem because its value may be changed implicitly by stuff in the "< do something with file >
" code.

Comment: @martineau: How would the `_` be implicitly changed? The <do something with file> only writes to and reads the file.

Comment: @DavidC: Sorry I was thinking what happens in the Python shell. It implicitly assigns the result of the last expression it evaluates into a variable named `_`.

Comment: Regardless, people usually reserved the use of variables named `_` to indicate those whose value isn't further used, which isn't the case in your example code (although this doesn't sound like it's what's causing your problem).

Comment: You say you're "using the with statement every time I open files". You do realize that the file created by `mkstemp()` is already open when the function returns -- i.e. you're not opening it again are you?

Comment: from ctypes import cdll libc = cdll.msvcrt libc._setmaxstdio(2048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) with `delete=False`?  This allows you to work with python file objects which is one bonus.  Also, it can be used as a context manager (which *should* take care of all the details making sure the file is properly closed):

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w',prefix=section,dir=indir,delete=False) as f:
     pass #Do something with the file here.
```

Comment: Why would this have a different effect than just calling mkstemp?

Comment: Running with _only_ this modification solved the problem, though I still don't understand why.

Comment: Using this approach works because you end up with the `file` object instead of a file descriptor (a number), management of file descriptor is encapsulated inside `NamedTemporaryFile`, and the code has no chance to mess with anything at that level, and `with` statement guarantees leaving everything closed and cleaned up once it exits.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have the same value stored in `_` at the time you call `os.close(_)` as at the time you created the temp file. Try assigning to a named variable instead of `_`.

If would help you and us if you could provide a very small code snippet that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I would like to get a small code snippet, but it's not really that easy, as I am unsure which piece is causing the problem (or when). The input is a several thousand line CSV file. When I try to reduce the input to find the problem, the error doesn't occur. The pattern I provided occurs frequently, but never does more than read from/write to the file as I mention in my post.

Comment: @DavidC Did it not help when you changed to `_file, _tmp = mkstemp(...) ... os.close(_file)`?

Comment: I'm still processing the code, so don't know yet, but I don't see why this would change anything. See martineau's comment to my question. At least, this is probably bad practice on my part.

Comment: @DavidC It's more readable and robust programming to do that, but it's possible it won't help. What if you print the value of `_`? In my experiment, `mkstemp()` reused the file descriptor number after I closed it. Since you are only operating on a few files at a time, you'll rule out the case where your file descriptor number is growing (which would indicate a problem realated to calls to `os.close`)? It's difficult to debug without seeing more code. :-)

Comment: The edit to the original post doesn't work for me when I insert it in place of "<do something with file>". After `out.close()`, it's not possible to do `os.fdopen(_)` on the same file descriptor.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It should have been `with open(_tmp) as p:`.